# Download PDF files at the first time with the Syncfusion flutter pdf viewer

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

I am using [Syncfusion flutter pdf viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer). Here, is it possible to download the PDF files while the file will be opened for the first time? So that from the next time onwards, it won't require an internet connection? If yes, how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to download the PDF file once and used them until the application is closed. The following code example explains how to ignore the multiple downloads of PDF when SfPdfViewer Widget is rebuilt or switched between different pages.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final String _url = 'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf';
  Uint8List _pdfBytes;

  // Downloads the PDF from the URL
  void downloadPDF()
  async {
    final HttpClient client = HttpClient();
    final HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(_url));
    final HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    _pdfBytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    setState(() {
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    downloadPDF();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('PDFVIEWER'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              _pdfBytes == null ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : SfPdfViewer.memory(
                  _pdfBytes),
              Text('Go back to first tab'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Dilli babu.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I want the downloaded PDFs will be stored on phone storage and will be opened up from there offline even after the application is closed and reopened. Is this possible?

Comment: @RifatHossain, Yes, with help of path_provider and SfPdfViewer.File() it possible to open the downloaded PDF from the phone storage. Please find the documentation link.

Reading a file from phone storage: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files#1-find-the-correct-local-path
Loading a File in SfPdfViewer: https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/latest/pdfviewer/SfPdfViewer/SfPdfViewer.file.html - Dilli babu